# How to bind backgroundcolor of WPF listview items?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and I have read a lot of similar questions on the web, but I still do not get my listview work. I want to change the background color of a list view element depending of a property (red, yellow or green)

The `itemsSource` of my ListView is an observable list of this class:

```
public class ConnectionItem 
{
    public ConnectionItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    private string _color = "Red";
    public string Color { get => _color; }
    private ConnectionStatus _status;
    public ConnectionStatus Status
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == _status)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case ConnectionStatus.Connected:
                        _color = "Yellow";
                        break;
                    case ConnectionStatus.Ready:
                        _color = "Green";
                        break;
                    default:
                        _color = "Red";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have defined my listview in xaml as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvConnections">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Green">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Red">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Yellow">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel  Width="150" MaxHeight="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The binding does not work and all my listview element have no background color. I do not need exactly the same solution via `ListView.Resources` binding, but I also have did not succed in other approaches.

Comment: why don't you return brush objects and bind the color to the property without triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the trigger `Style` from `ListView.Resources` to `StackPanel.Resources` (and change the `TargetType` to `StackPanel`) then the background colors will display using this approach.

```
<StackPanel  Width="150" MaxHeight="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Green">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Red">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Yellow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You will also need to look at implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `ConnectionItem` for the colors to update when `Status` is changed.

```
public class ConnectionItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public ConnectionItem(string name)
      {
          Name = name;
      }

      public string Name { get; }

      private string _color = "Red";
      public string Color
      {
          get => _color;
          set
          {
              if (value == _color) return;
              _color = value;
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Color"));
          }
      }

      private ConnectionStatus _status;
      public ConnectionStatus Status
      {
          get => _status;
          set
          {
              if (value == _status) return;
              _status = value;
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));
              switch (value)
              {
                  case ConnectionStatus.Connected:
                      Color = "Yellow";
                      break;
                  case ConnectionStatus.Ready:
                      Color = "Green";
                      break;
                  default:
                      Color = "Red";
                      break;
              }               
          }
      }
  }
```

Note that `Status` and `Color` now have both `get` and `set` accessors and that
that `Status` is setting the `Color` property rather than directly setting the `_color` field.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();

          lvConnections.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionItem>()
          {
              new ConnectionItem("Starts Connected") { Status = ConnectionStatus.Connected, },
              new ConnectionItem("Starts Ready") { Status = ConnectionStatus.Ready, },
              new ConnectionItem("Starts Default"),
          };
      }

      private void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
          var item = (sender as ListViewItem)?.DataContext as ConnectionItem;
          switch (item.Status)
          {
              case ConnectionStatus.Connected:
                  item.Status = ConnectionStatus.Ready;
                  break;
              case ConnectionStatus.Ready:
                  item.Status = ConnectionStatus.Disconnected;
                  break;
              default:
                  item.Status = ConnectionStatus.Connected;
                  break;
          }
      }
  }
```

You can even go one step further, remove the `Color` property from `ConnectionItem` altogether (and the switch setting it in `Status`) and use `Status` values in the `Style` triggers.

**ConnectionItem**

```
public class ConnectionItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ConnectionItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    private ConnectionStatus _status;
    public ConnectionStatus Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set
        {
            if (value == _status) return;
            _status = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Style**

```
  <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Ready">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Disconnected">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Connected">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I have seen this approach with implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged, but I for my case it is too much code for such a smal functionality. The little changes from @mm8 will also do it for my use case I think

Comment: You're welcome. INotifyPropertyChanged is pretty fundamental to xaml binding though. You're going to need to implement it if you want the color of the ListViewItem to change from it's initial value by changing the ConnectionItem.There are more re-usable ways of implementing it, but I went with the most basic. You can even use the PropertyChanged.Fody nuget package which will *almost* automagically do it for you.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I want the values change from it initial values. So I think I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface

Answer (score 1):

bind the background to the Color property.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvConnections">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel  Width="150" MaxHeight="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

and set the Color property to a brush object

```
public class ConnectionItem 
{
    public ConnectionItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    private Brush _color = Brushes.Red;
    public Brush Color { get => _color; }
    private ConnectionStatus _status;
    public ConnectionStatus Status
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == _status)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case ConnectionStatus.Connected:
                        _color = Brushes.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case ConnectionStatus.Ready:
                        _color = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    default:
                        _color = Brushes.Red;
                        break;
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution sounds great, because once could dynamically change to any color and not just to my red green yellow string values... But if I apply your changes, there are still no background colors for the items. Not even the initial color "Brushes.Red"

Answer (score 1):

Your `ListViewItem` style doesn't get applied because your have set the `ItemContainerStyle` property to another `Style`. You should move your triggers to the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvConnections">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Green">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Red">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Yellow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel  Width="150" MaxHeight="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Great! Works so far also with Brush type instead of string values. I will mark this answer if i have tested some value swithing

Comment: @team17: You mean *when* you have tested? For "value switching" to work, you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the PropertyChanged event in your ConnectionItem class.